# Can Polish citizens get a visa to Guyana in Brazil?

Tags: visas, polish-citizens, guyana

Looking at website of [Guyanese Embassy in Brasilia, Brazil](http://www.embguyana.org.br/visaenglish.htm) I'm not sure if they issue visas to foreigners:

> We advise that Brazilians do not need a tourism visa to get into Guyana (...) Fees: touristic visa - R$45,00 (...)

Since they mention that Brazilians don't need a touristic visa and yet publish its price, I understand they issue visas to foreigners. There's also a [visa form](http://www.embguyana.org.br/visaform.htm) in English available on their website.

On the other hand, according to [Polish MFA](http://www.caracas.msz.gov.pl/pl/wspolpraca_dwustronna/informacje_ekonomiczne/kraje_akredytacje/gujana/) (information available in Polish only)

> You can apply for a visa in Guyanese Embassy in Brussels or Caracas, Venezuela

My question is, as a citizen of Poland and resident of Brazil, can I get Guyanese visa in Brasilia, Brazil?

Comment: English version worked just fine for me just now - http://www.embguyana.org.br/visaenglish.htm . But it says the same, which to me sounds like they do offer visas to other ntionalities.

Comment: Ah thanks, you're right, I updated the link. Before I tried only entering from their main site where the link is dead http://www.embguyana.org.br/

Comment: @Kuba Poles do Need visas for Guyana, though if you have a letter of Invitation from a host (such as a Hotel) you can get it on arrival

Comment: @Crazydre ah, really? That would be helpful, can you tell me where you found this info? Polish MFA doesn't mention anything...

Comment: @Kuba Timatic, the database used by Airlines (read blow "Visa Issuance" https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PL&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GY&selDest=Guyana&selTrans=Use+ctrl-key+to+select+or+deselect+transit+point%28s%29+above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C

Comment: @Crazydre thank you, just to make sure - is it still a valid option when crossing by land (Bonfim/Lethem) border? Or can Timatic be 100% trusted only with air transport?

Comment: @Kuba It's only 100% by air I'm afraid, but very often by land too. Don't know about Guyanese land borders though. Embassies of these countries also rarely have the full info. If I had a phone number to the border post, I'd call and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to reach them by phone, they said that I can get a visa in any Brazilian consulate (except the one in Brasilia there are ones in Rio de Janeiro and São Paulo, I haven't seen them mentioned on the embassy website).
The process takes up to 5 working days.

Answer (score 0):

If a country doesn't have an embassy, that country (Poland in this case) falls into the jurisdiction of the nearest embassy, which in Europe seems to be in Brussels and in South America in Caracas. So the Polish MFA website is advising the citizens about the most convenient embassies to apply at.

That said, if the destination country allows visa application to be filed in any embassy in the world, then you can theoretically apply not just to the one in Brasilia but any Guyanese embassy.

Comment: I understand, my worry was mostly about why my MFA mentions only two consulates in the world, while Caracas is not so convenient to visit for anyone but Venezuelans. But as I mentioned in my answer, they confirmed on the phone I can go to any consulate.